# AspectJ: Injecting aspects to project as a third party library

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, aspect

There are 2 projects:

- Test project **A** (contain a simple class with the `main` method with the output of the message "*It's A project"*);
- Project **B** contain aspects (*.aj) for processing the message output to the console (e.q. displaying the "*It's aspect from B project*" message before every message output to the console in project **A**), + additional classes.

Projects **A** and **B** are based on the [Spring Framework](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/). Project **B** contains aspects that used the `percflow` model, which is [currently not supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-instantiation-models) by Spring.

Can I compile aspects using the [AspectJ compiler](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/antTasks-iajc.html) without using the project **A** (hence without `compile-time`/`post-compile` weaving) and then, on the basis of project **B** build a jar file that I can add to **A** project dependencies for further usage?

That is at a stage of assembly of the jar-file the project **B** knows nothing of the project **A**.

It will probably be necessary to use `load-time` weaving. How exactly should Spring be configured to automatically pick up aspects from the **B** project's jar file  when it is added to project **A**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible:

- How to use AspectJ LTW is desribed in the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.13.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw).
- How to set up your Maven build for project B is described in the [AspectJ Maven plugin manual](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/).

Sorry for not answering in more detail, but your question is also quite theoretical, you neither show any code or build information nor do you share a link to a sample project on GitHub. Creating an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help the community to write better answers.